# Visual Studio 2015 hangs when opening property page on right click menu

Tags: c#, visual-studio, process, vs-web-site-project

I have a website project and Visual Studio hangs when I right click on the project name in solution explorer and click property page.

I tried to find out what VS is doing by Process Monitor and it shows that VS keeps looking for `%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\ApplicationInsights\vstelf144292e-e3b2-4011-ac90-20e5c03fbce5\*.trn` and the result is `NO SUCH FILE`, I looked and the location is an empty folder.

I found a solution suggest that creating an empty `a.trn` file in the above location. I tried and ProcMon shows the file is found but VS still get stuck in a loop searching for `*.trn` file.

VS did showed the Property Page after a very long time, but it hangs again when I try to close the solution, and ProcMon shows VS still trying to find `*.trn` file this time.

Also, when I build the website it hangs at `Validating Web Site` stage, ProcMon shows it is also because VS keeps looking for `*.trn` file in the above location even if my `a.trn` is present.

I don't have Application Insights installed.

Does anybody have a clue what is going on?

Comment: Did you receive any errors when installing VS2015? Any other versions installed? Admin rights to your machine? Which edition of Visual Studio? Anything in the event log?

Comment: Also, congrats on getting it installed at all. I'm 0 for 3 machines.

Comment: No error when installing VS2015. No other versions installed. Tried giving admin to VS but doesn't help, it still keeps looking in `AppData\Local\Microsoft\ApplicationInsights` folder. In event log I can see `The program devenv.exe version 14.0.25123.0 stopped interacting with Windows and was closed.` but It is because I ended devenv.exe process when it hangs.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the cause of the problem and it has nothing to do with Application Insights.

I started aspnet_compiler.exe in command line to build the solution and in ProcMon I can see it keeps making TCP reconnection to my company's db server, the solution points to a db sitting on that server, I realized I need to add my home router's ip in server's firewall inbound rule, and all working fine now.